# Opening platform specific screens after login screen in cross platform shared code Xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, cross-platform

I want to open an Android activity for Android devices and iOS screen for iOS devices from login screen. The code of the login screen, I have written is in shared portable code Area. I have used interface and #if *ANDROID* #endif, but it is also not working.
Android screen will only contain a textview and an iOS screen will contain a Image. This is my Login Page in portable folder

```
namespace DemoApp
{
    public class HomePage : ContentPage
    {
        public HomePage()
        {
            var title = new Label
            {
                Text = "Welcome to CloudCakes",
                FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label)),
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            };


            var email = new Entry
            {
                Placeholder = "E-Mail",
            };

            var password = new Entry
            {
                Placeholder = "Password",
                IsPassword = true
            };

            var login = new Button
            {
                Text = "Login"
            };

            // With the `PushModalAsync` method we navigate the user
            // the the orders page and do not give them an option to
            // navigate back to the Homepage by clicking the back button
            login.Clicked += (sender, e) =>
         {
             App.UserPreferences.Open();
             // await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new MainPage());
         };

            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Padding = 30,
                Spacing = 10,
                Children = { title, email, password, login}
            };
        }
    }
}
```

And, this is the page in Droid folder where I want to navigate on clicking login button
`name space 
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Page1 : IUserPreferences
    {
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void Open()
        {
            var title = new Label
            {
                Text = "Welcome to Xamarin Forms IOS Screen!!",
                FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Large, typeof(Label)),
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            };
            Content = new StackLayout
            {
                Padding = 30,
                Spacing = 10,
                Children = { title }
            };
        }
    }
}`

Open is a method of interface which is present in the portable folder.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you're using Xamarin.Forms, so what you need to do is actually quite easy to achieve.

Instead of having a separate page for each platform, create one new XAML page with the following code:

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="YourApp.Views.MainPage">
  <ContentView>
    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="View">
      <OnPlatform.iOS>
        <Image Source="something.png" />
      </OnPlatform.iOS>
      <OnPlatform.Android>
        <Label Text="Android" />
      </OnPlatform.Android>
    </OnPlatform>
  </ContentView>
</ContentPage>
```

This way you can control what to have on the page for each platform.

To navigate to MainPage from your LoginPage, you need to implement the Clicked event (or preferrably use [Commands](https://blog.xamarin.com/simplifying-events-with-commanding/)) in the code behind (MainPage.xaml.cs) and do the navigation there:

```
private void SomeButton_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    await this.Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
}
```

In the long run, you should look into doing all this outside the code behind with ViewModel's and Commands.

---

**Edit:** Since the first solution didn't work for you, here's what to do:

1) Subclass ContentPage in your core project.

```
public class MainPage : ContentPage { }
```

2) Implement a PageRenderer for each platform separately. You'll be able to use native layout definition for your pages as you mentioned.

There's a [great article](https://blog.xamarin.com/customize-your-xamarin-forms-app-with-pages-for-each-platform/) on the Xamarin blog on how to achieve this. You can also find the [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/pierceboggan/Moments).

Comment: in which folder i will add the image and how can i call this view to run from login button click?

Comment: thanks mate. Code is running fine, but i want a separate layout file in my Droid folder for android and separate file in iOS for iOS layout. On clicking the login button in our portable folder respective file will open depending on the platform of the device..

Comment: @aman Got it, I edited my answer once more. You can definitely load a platform specific layout in Xamarin.Forms.

Comment: sorry but I am not able to understand what I am doing wrong?? 
could you please tell me step by step?? what I have to do in this situation?

Comment: @aman It's impossible to say without seeing the code you're using. Also, my instructions are already step by step with links to a working sample and a blog post explaining it.

Comment: I have edited my question with the code.
I have used an interface which is in the portable folder having method void Open in it, and it  is implemented by all the platform specific  folders of the project.